# Ignite Transaction in Read Commited Mode not consistent

Tags: transactions, ignite

We use Ignite transactions in READ_COMMITED mode and we also use Optimistic Offline Lock design pattern to meet data consistency requirements and latency while reading. It is important for our bussiness not to see partial updated data in caches while reading. REPEATABLE_READ blocks our reads that is why we do not use it.

Read transaction:

```
@Override
public SearchResult apply(ComputeTaskInData<SearchProductOffer> data) {
    while (true) {
        try (Transaction tx = ignite.transactions().txStart(PESSIMISTIC, READ_COMMITTED)) {
            Long initialTimestamp = getCurrentTimestampFromIgniteCache();
            ... // multiple caches read where we can see commited data in the middle of read
            Long finalTimestamp = getCurrentTimestampFromigniteCache();

            // Check if transaction was commited in the middle of read request. If so, retry. This 
               timestamp increments in update transaction.
            if (finalTimestamp > initialTimestamp) continue;

            return readResult;
    }
```

}

Update transaction:

```
        try (Transaction transaction = ignite.transactions().txStart(PESSIMISTIC, REPEATABLE_READ)) {
        // Multiple caches update.
           IgniteCache<OfflineLockKey, Long> offerOfflineLock = 
                                               ignite.getOrCreateCache(OFFLINE_LOCK.name());
            OfflineLockKey offlineLockKey = new 
                                    OfflineLockKey(segmentIndex.segmentInfo.getSegmentId());
            Long offerTimestamp = offerOfflineLock.get(offlineLockKey);
            if (offerTimestamp == null) {
                offerTimestamp = 0L;
            }
            offerTimestamp++;
            offerOfflineLock.put(offlineLockKey, offerTimestamp);

            transaction.commit();
        }
```

But the problem is, we read inconsistent data and don't retry. It seems that ignite transaction is not atomic, and we don't get incremented timestamp. Is it supposed behaviour of PESSIMISTIC READ_COMMITED mode?
We tried different cache modes for offline_lock cache.
And yes,  all caches are TRANSACTIONAL.

Answer (score 0):

The problem on my side was the cache configuration.

You must obtain your cache with that config (in my case it's my local cache)

```
     ingite.getOrCreateCache(new CacheConfiguration("cacheName")
                    .setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL)
                    .setCacheMode(CacheMode.LOCAL));
```